# Scheme remove adjacent duplicates

Tags: list, scheme

Trying to implement a procedure that removes adjacent duplicates. It takes a list as input and returns as value the same list with any sequence of repeated elements reduced to a single element:

Example:

```
(remove-adjacent-duplicates ’(y a b b a d a b b a d o o))
'(y a b a d a b a d o)

(remove-adjacent-duplicates ’(yeah yeah yeah))
'(yeah)
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

If the argument is the empty list or the `cdr` is the empty list then the result is the argument.

Else if the first and the second element is the same, then skip the first element.

Else `cons` the first element with the recursion with the `cdr` or the argument.. eg.

```
(remove-adjacent-duplicates '(a b)) ; ==
(cons (car '(a b)) (remove-adjacent-duplicates (cdr '(a b))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution - first we check if the list is empty, if not - check for duplicates by chunks.

```
(define (strip-duplicates ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      '()
      (let ((first (car ls)))
        (let loop ((known first)
                   (rest (cdr ls))
                   (so-far (list first)))
          (if (null? rest)
              (reverse so-far)
              (let ((first-remaining (car rest)))
                (loop first-remaining
                      (cdr rest)
                      (if (equal? known first-remaining)
                          so-far
                          (cons first-remaining so-far)))))))))
```

Comment: code-only answers might get automatically flagged as low quality.